# (android) how to overwrite image on DCIM folder?

Tags: android

I already have a resized bitmap object.

with this bitmap, how can i overwrite this bitmap in DCIM folder??

I know that I should change the bitmap into File object...

please help me

(Assume that i also have the absolute path)

I tried this with the code below. 
It creates a new file only if a file with same name doesn't exist. 
Otherwise, it doesn't create a new file.

```
private void SaveBitmapToFileCache(Bitmap bitmap, String strFilePath) {

    File fileCacheItem = new File(strFilePath);
    OutputStream out = null;

    try
    {
        fileCacheItem.createNewFile();
        out = new FileOutputStream(fileCacheItem);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run a condition, wherein if the file exists, delete it and go on with creating a new one!

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//File file= new File("FilePath"+ "/myfolder/myimage.jpg");
    if(fileCacheItem .exists())
    {
         file.delete();
    }
```